# Windows Yes, Linux No - JSF not rendering

Tags: java, linux, jsf, tomcat, jsf-2

I have a very strange problem, an application developed using JSF/Richfaces runs on Tomcat under windows but not under linux. The Windows server has Tomcat 6.0.39 and the Linux one 6.0.35, the only other difference is that the Linux Tomcat is accessed through ajp13.

Exactly the same files were deployed to the webapps folder on both servers, the Windows server performs as it should but the Linux one renders the JSF page as an XML file when using Chrome, for Firefox and IE is just displays the text it recognises but the rest of the JAS page is visible if you view the source.

I have check the obvious like permissions and the case of the characters in file names, I have also deleted the Tomcat work folders and tried again.

One strange effect is that the XML rendered starts with

The web.xml looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">
  <display-name>zuzz</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>zuzz/index.xhtml</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>org.richfaces.skin</param-name>
    <param-value>blueSky</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <mime-mapping>
    <extension>ecss</extension>
    <mime-type>text/css</mime-type>
  </mime-mapping>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>com.sun.faces.validateXml</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>com.sun.faces.verifyObjects</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.INTERPRET_EMPTY_STRING_SUBMITTED_VALUES_AS_NULL</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.coherence-preserve-attributes</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.DATETIMECONVERTER_DEFAULT_TIMEZONE_IS_SYSTEM_TIMEZONE</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>facelets.SKIP_COMMENTS</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Resource Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.richfaces.webapp.ResourceServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Resource Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/org.richfaces.resources/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

The faces-config.xml looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<faces-config version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
              xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude"
              xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
              xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_0.xsd">
<lifecycle>
    <phase-listener>com.patcomsys.utils.JsfPhaseListener</phase-listener>
</lifecycle>
</faces-config>
```

The template xhtml file looks like this

```
<h:html xmlns="http://www.w3c.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
          xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j"
          xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
  <h:head>
    <title>Zuzz Internet Services</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="zuzz.css"/>
  <f:metadata>
    <f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{accountBean.wakeUp}" />
    <f:viewParam name="ac" value="#{loginBean.zuzzAccountId}" />
    <f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{loginBean.setAccount}" />
  </f:metadata>


    <ui:insert name="metadata"></ui:insert> 

  </h:head>

  <h:body >
        <div style="width:895; margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;">
          <ui:insert name="banner">
            <ui:include src="#{accountBean.bannerPage}" />
          </ui:insert>
        </div>
        <div id="log-in" style="width:960px;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;position:relative;top:280px;">
         <ui:insert name="login">
        <ui:include src="login.xhtml" />
         </ui:insert>
    </div>
    <table style="width:960px;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;position:relative;top:100px;"><TBODY style="align-content:center;"><tr><td>
     <ui:insert name="body"></ui:insert>
        </td></tr></TBODY></table>
  </h:body>

</h:html>
```

(Yes I know it has in-line styling - this will be moved to a css file :-) )

I have tried all suggestions that I have found in SO and have run out of ideas

Comment: Check all the available logs like server logs, etc for any useful error messages

Comment: There are no errors in the catalina.log file

Comment: I have found the cause of the problem. The request was not getting as far as Tomcat, this was the first use of .xhtml files on the server and the Apache configuration required a mapping for ajp13 and .xhtml in order to route the requests through to Tomcat